# Parallel.ForEach дублирует элементы в BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel

Разрабатываю текстовый поиск товаров по коллекции в памяти. Сам поиск не простой, учитывается множество вариантов написания. Есть возможность поиска нескольких товаров за раз, разделив их через запятую или другой разделитель. **Поэтому, было решено распараллелить поиск при помощи Parallel.ForEach**

Проблема заключается в том, что иногда результирующая коллекция возвращает дубликаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При первом поиске после старта приложения всё норм (скриншот слева). После второго поиска вышли дубликаты (скриншот справа)

```
public partial class SearchEngine<T> 
{
    public List<T> OriginalCollection { get; set; }

    public List<T> SearchParallel(string searchText, SearchEngineOptions options)
    {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText?.Trim()))
                return OriginalCollection;

            //List<T> result = new List<T>();
            BlockingCollection<T> result = new BlockingCollection<T>();

            if (options == null)
            {
                options = new SearchEngineOptions()
                {
                    Separators = new List<char>() { ',', '\n' }
                };
            }

            //разделить строки для множественного поиска
             var splitText = searchText
                .Split(options.Separators.ToArray())
                .Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w?.Trim()))
                .Distinct();

            //установка ограничения в 20 элементов за раз
            if (splitText.Length > 20)
                splitText = splitText
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToArray();

            if (splitText.Count() == 1)
            {
                return Search(searchText);
            }

            var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
            {
               //MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(splitText, parallelOptions, (s) =>
            {
                var searchResult = Search(s);

                foreach (var item in searchResult)
                {
                    result.TryAdd(item);
                }
            });

            return result.ToList();
      }

      public List<T> Search(string searchText)
      {
         //поиск товаров
      }
}
```

Использую потокобезопасную коллекцию **BlockingCollection**, но увы не работает.

**Платформа .NET 4.6.1**

**Какие еще нюансы нужно учитывать при параллельном поиске?**

Comment: А почему виноват Parallel? Почему сразу не работает BlockingCollection? Search возвращает одинаковые результаты для разных запросов, нормальная ситуация, вот и весь ответ. Так что просто самостоятельно уберите дубликаты из коллекции

Answer (score 3):

`Использую потокобезопасную коллекцию BlockingCollection, но увы не работает.` У вас не работает ваша логика в коде.

1. Что за текст вы в него передаете?
2. Что вы делаете внутри `public List<T> Search(string searchText)`?
3. Зачем вам вообще `BlockingCollection`?
4. Зачем тут `Parallel.ForEach` ?
5. Что это и зачем тут это `OriginalCollection` ?

Ваш код можно переписать так

```
public partial class SearchEngine<T>
{
    public List<T> OriginalCollection { get; set; }

    public List<T> SearchParallel(string searchText, SearchEngineOptions options)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText?.Trim()))
            return OriginalCollection;
        
        var splitText = SplitSearchText(searchText, options);
        
        return  splitText
                    .AsParallel()
                    // .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
                    .SelectMany(x=>Search(x))
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();  
    }
    
    IEnumerable<string> SplitSearchText(string searchText, SearchEngineOptions options)
    {
        //разделить строки для множественного поиска
        return searchText
           .Split(options.Separators.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w?.Trim()))
           .Distinct()
           .Take(20);   
    }

    public List<T> Search(string searchText)
    {
        //поиск товаров
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.OriginalCollection - это ссылка на коллекцию, где хранятся уникальные товары. Пример,есть 3 "анаферона" с разной дозировкой, и 3 "кеппра" с разной дозировкой.Передаю я следующий текст "анаферон, кеппра" и иногда я получаю 6 анаферонов с дубликатами, но без кеппра, или наоборот. В какие-то моменты выводится нормально,3 анаферона, 3 кеппра.То есть товары дублируются не всегда.Если заменить Parallel.ForEach на обычный foreach - работает хорошо, дубликатов на выходе нет.Что посоветуете использовать вместо BlockingCollection?Я читал, что ConcurrentBag проседает в производительности

Comment: `Что посоветуете использовать вместо BlockingCollection` я же переписал ваш пример, это и посоветую. Ну и вы не показываете никакого кода для `OriginalCollection`, потому что у вас там не работает и почему можно только гадать.

Comment: Всё, спасибо, Вы оказались правы. Результирующая коллекция была как свойство класса (чтобы можно было обратиться к последним результатам поиска, не осуществляя поиск повторно ) и оно постоянно перезаписывалось в методе Search, попросту забыл об этом. В следующий раз буду внимателен. Спасибо.

Comment: На здоровье! Рад, что у вас вс заработало.